# If the union of $A$ and $B$ is linearly independent then the intersection of the spans $= \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\newcommand{\sp}{\operatorname{sp}}$ Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ field, and let $A,B$ be two different, disjoint, non-empty sets of vectors from $V$.
>
> Prove or disprove the following:
> If $A \cup B$ are linearly independent, $\sp(A) \cap \sp(B) = \{0\}$.

It's an easy one to example over $\mathbb{R}^2$, because the $\text{span}$ of all $\mathbb{R}^2$ vectors has $(0,0)$ in it, but something keeps telling me that it might be disproved for other vector spaces.

Comment: If $sp(A) \cap sp(B) \neq \{0\}$, then there would be linear dependence.

Comment: If $\sum \alpha_i a_i=\sum \beta_jb_j$ then  $\sum \alpha_i a_i+\sum (-\beta_j)b_j=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$x\in Sp(A)\cap Sp(B)\implies \exists\,a_1,...,a_k\in A\;,\;b_1,...,b_m\in B\,,\,c_1,...,c_{k+m}\in \Bbb F\;\;s.t.$$

$$x=\sum_{i=1}^kc_ia_i=\sum_{i=1}^mc_{k+1}b_i\implies c_1a_1+\ldots c_ka_k-c_{k+1}b_1-\ldots c_mb_m=0\implies$$

$$\implies c_r=0\;\;\forall r=1,\ldots,m\;,\;\text{since}\;a_i,b_k\in A\cup B\ldots$$

Comment: I'm always up for hints, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $v$ be a vector
$$v\in\operatorname{sp}(A)\cap\operatorname{sp}(B)$$
Since $v\in\operatorname{sp}(A)$ you can write
$$v=\sum_jf_ja_j$$
for some $f_j\in F,a_j\in A$. Similarly, since $v\in\operatorname{sp}(B)$, you can also write
$$v=\displaystyle\sum_ig_ib_i$$
for some $g_i\in F,b_i\in B$.
Then you get
$$\displaystyle\sum_jf_ja_j-\displaystyle\sum_ig_ib_i=0$$
but LHS is a linear combination of vectors in $A\cup B$, hence by assumptions linearly indipendent, thus all coefficients are zero, implying that $v=0$

Answer (score 0):

It's true. Suppose $A \cup B$ is linearly independent. Assume by contradiction that the intersection of the spans contains a vector $x \neq 0$. Suppose $A = \{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ and $B = \{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ so that 
$$
x = \alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_m v_m = \beta_1 w_1 + \cdots + \beta_n w_n.
$$
However, subtracting the RHS from the LHS gives
$$
\alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_m v_m - \beta_1 w_1 - \dots - \beta_n w_n = 0
$$
and since $A \cup B$ is linearly independent, that implies $\alpha_i = \beta_j = 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1\leq j \leq n$. This is a contradiction since this would imply $x = 0$. Thus, the intersection of the spans must only contain the zero vector.