# $(u_1,\ldots,u_k,v_1,\ldots,v_l)$ is linearly ind. iff $\operatorname{span}(u_1,\ldots,u_k) \cap (\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_l) = \{0\} $

Tags: linear-algebra

> Assume that $(u_1,\ldots,u_k)$ and $(v_1,\ldots,v_l)$ are linearly independent. Prove that $(u_1,\ldots,u_k,v_1,\ldots,v_l)$ is linearly independent if and only if $\operatorname{span}(u_1,\ldots,u_k) \cap \operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_l) = \{0\}.$

I've had trouble making any progress beyond rattling off that $\alpha_1u_1+\cdots+\alpha_k u_k + \beta_1 v_1 + \cdots + \beta_l v_l = 0$ implies that the $\alpha_i,\beta_j$ are all $0.$ Not asking for a detailed answer, I would just like a hint. Thank you

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392636/if-the-union-of-a-and-b-is-linearly-independent-then-the-intersection-of-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha_1u_1+\cdots+\alpha_k u_k =- \beta_1 v_1 - \cdots - \beta_l v_l$ right hand is $\in {span}(u_1,\ldots,u_k)$ and left hand $\in {span}(v_1,\ldots,v_l)$ thus
$\operatorname{span}(u_1,\ldots,u_k) \cap (\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_l) = \{0\} $ so $\alpha_1u_1+\cdots+\alpha_k u_k =0$ and $- \beta_1 v_1 - \cdots - \beta_l v_l=0$ use  linearly independent you will get result.