# If $\{u_1,\dots,u_r, w_1,\dots,w_s\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, how to prove that $\text{span}(u_i) \cap\ \text{span}(w_j) = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove if $\{u_1,\dots,u_r, w_1,\dots,w_s\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, then $\text{span}(u_i) \cap\  \text{span}(w_j) = \{0\}$

Comment: Use contradiction....

Comment: What happens if a nonzero multiple of some $u_i$ is equal to a nonzero multiple of some $w_j?$

Comment: I know it's almost obvious, but the first line of the proof basically has to be "Suppose that $x\in\mathop{\rm span}(u_i)\cap\mathop{\rm span}(w_j)$, and the last line of the proof basically has to be "Therefore $x=0$. That first line gives you two facts about $x$, from the definition of span. Combining those two facts should allow you to invoke the hypothesis on linear independence....

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467922/u-1-ldots-u-k-v-1-ldots-v-l-is-linearly-ind-iff-operatornamespanu-1?rq=1 this may help

Comment: thanks, everyone. I managed to solve it.